# Firestore pricing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There are several questions asked about this topic but I cant find one that answers my question. As [described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations), there is no clear explanation as to whether the minimum charges are applicable to `query.get()` or real-time listeners as well. Quoted:

> There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results.

**The reason am asking this question** even though it may seem obvious for someone is due to the section; `*for each query that you perform*` in that statement which could mean a one time trigger e.g with `get()` method.

**Scenario:** If 10 users are listening to changes in a collection **with queries** i.e `query.addSnapshotListener()` then change occurs in one document which matches query filter of only two users, are the other eight charged a cost of one read too?

**Database used:**  Firestore

Comment: To clarify billing issues, you should contact Firebase support directly.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Should point out you said your databased used was Firestore but your tag on the post is for firebase-realtime-database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario I would say no, the other eight would not be counted as reads because the documents they are listening to have not been updated or have not been added/removed from that collection based on their filters (query params). The reads aren't based on changes to the collection but rather changes to the stream of documents you are specifically listening to. Because that 1 document change was not part of the documents that the other 8 users were listening to then there is no new read for them. However, if that 1 document change led to that document now matching the query filters of those other 8, then yes there would be 8 new reads for those users. Hope that makes sense.

Also it's worth noting that things like have offlinePersistence enabled via the sdk and firestore's caching maximize the efficiency of limiting reads as well as using a singleton Observable that multiple instances in your app subscribe to as oppose to opening multiple streams of the same query throughout your app. Doesn't really apply to this question directory but again while in the same vein, it's worth noting.